# HTML formatting issue on voting button

Tags: bug, status-completed

This may be a more generic Stack issue, but I'm raising it here as I've only seen it here.

My rep on the site is low, so I don't have the ability to vote. The dialogue to inform me I can't vote has an HTML formatting issue.

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce the same problem on other SE sites where I have less than 125 reputation, so it appears to affect all of SE. I would migrate it to the general meta, but [there is already a post about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/badly-escaped-html-results-in-plain-text-where-there-should-be-markup-in-toast-n).

Comment: Cool, thank you.

Comment: As of 1 hour ago, [this has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377798/388335)